# VC++ Library Miss while compiling application? unzip.obj : error LNK2019

Tags: c++, zip, zlib

I try to compile VC++ application and get the error message as below. Is there anyone who know what the library I may be missing? Any advice & suggestion are appreciated.

My Environment:

1. VC++ 2010
2. zlib-1.2.8
3. boost_1_57_0
4. icu

```
1>------ Build started: Project: paloserver, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>     Creating library C:/Users/a992788/Virtual Machines/Documents/Application/Palo/Palo 3.x Source Code/palo-code-546/molap/server/5.1/SourceCode/Debug/paloserver.lib and object C:/Users/a992788/Virtual Machines/Documents/Application/Palo/Palo 3.x Source Code/palo-code-546/molap/server/5.1/SourceCode/Debug/paloserver.exp

1>unzip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateInit2_ referenced in function _unzOpenCurrentFile3

1>unzip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflate referenced in function _unzReadCurrentFile

1>unzip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crc32 referenced in function _unzReadCurrentFile

1>zip.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crc32

1>unzip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateEnd referenced in function _unzCloseCurrentFile

1>zip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _get_crc_table referenced in function _zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64

1>zip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateInit2_ referenced in function _zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64

1>zip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate referenced in function _zipWriteInFileInZip

1>zip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd referenced in function _zipCloseFileInZipRaw64

1>C:\Users\a992788\Virtual Machines\Documents\Application\Palo\Palo 3.x Source Code\palo-code-546\molap\server\5.1\SourceCode\Debug\paloserver.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

Comment: `zlib-1.2.8`'s file or library is missing. Check tutorial on how to use zlib properly in MSVC.

Comment: Hi Mohit, should I compile the libz by myself or? it doesn't work even if I add "zdll.lib" into VC library and copy "zlib1.dll" into system32.

Comment: There should be an option to add "Additional library files" or add all zlib files into your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to the zdll.lib in your source.

```
#pragma comment (lib, "zdll.lib")
```

Comment: Hi Ari0nhh, a from the answer, is there anyway to include the library into VC++?

Comment: There is a zdll.lib file in the distribution achive. You should create a folder somewhere in your solution catalog, put lib file here and then add path to it in the project options (Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ directories->Library directories)